# Extended Member class still attempting to write to Member table

Tags: silverstripe

I am extending the member table to include basic address details.

**Setup:**

```
class ClientMember extends Member {

    private static $db = array(
        "AddressLine1" => "Varchar(255)",
        "AddressLine2" => "Varchar(255)",
        "Country"      => "Varchar(50)",
        "State"        => "Varchar(50)",
        "Postcode"     => "Int(4)"
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $addressLine1 = new TextField('AddressLine1', 'Address line 1', null, 255);
        $addressLine2 = new TextField('AddressLine2', 'Address line 2', null, 255);
        $country      = new CountryDropdownField('Country', 'Country', null, 'AU');
        $state        = new DropdownField('State', 'State', array('vic' => 'Victoria', 'sa' => 'South Australia', 'wa' => 'Western Australia'));
        $postcode     = new NumericField('Postcode', 'Postcode', null, 4);

        $fields->addFieldsToTab(
            'Root.Address',
            array(
                $addressLine1,
                $addressLine2,
                $country,
                $state,
                $postcode
            )
        );

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

I am then telling SilverStripe to use the new the class name of `ClientMember` in YAML config.

```
Injector:
  Member:
    class: ClientMember
```

**The Issue:**

I can then create new 'Client Members' through the CMS and the new Adress tab and fields all work as expected. When I save I get the following error:

> string 'Couldn't run query:  UPDATE "Member" SET "AddressLine1" =
>   'Test', "AddressLine2" = 'Test', "Country" = 'AU', "State" = 'vic',
>   "Postcode" = 1212, "LastEdited" = '2015-07-10 12:43:58' where "ID" =
>   10
>
> Unknown column 'AddressLine1' in 'field list'' (length=245)

Notice it is trying to write the new fields into `Member` table and not the extended `ClientMember` table.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you clarify if you are trying to replace Member with ClientMember altogether or if you want to have both ClientMember and Member?

Comment: I am trying to replace (extend) Members. In an ideal world they would be separate but I want to reuse all of the login functionality that comes with Member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that I would do this is by extending `Member` with a `DataExtension` like so:

#### ClientMember

```
class ClientMember extends DataExtension {

    private static $db = array(
        "AddressLine1" => "Varchar(255)",
        "AddressLine2" => "Varchar(255)",
        "Country"      => "Varchar(50)",
        "State"        => "Varchar(50)",
        "Postcode"     => "Int(4)"
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {

        $addressLine1 = TextField::create('AddressLine1', 'Address line 1', null, 255);
        $addressLine2 = TextField::create('AddressLine2', 'Address line 2', null, 255);
        $country      = CountryDropdownField::create('Country', 'Country', null, 'AU');
        $state        = DropdownField::create('State', 'State', array('vic' => 'Victoria', 'sa' => 'South Australia', 'wa' => 'Western Australia'));
        $postcode     = NumericField::create('Postcode', 'Postcode', null, 4);

        $fields->addFieldsToTab(
            'Root.Address',
            array(
                $addressLine1,
                $addressLine2,
                $country,
                $state,
                $postcode
            )
        );
    }
}
```

#### config.yml

```
Member:
  extensions:
    - ClientMember
```

Comment: @nickspiel To add more explanation to this: all new data will be in ClientMember (so address and all that), but Member table will still be there and when you save a new Member you use that class instead of ClientMember.... So read how Extensions work to get a better understanding on it :)

Comment: I swapped it over to this new setup now when I access the Security tab I get the following: 'Call to undefined method ClientMember::setSourceQueryParams()'

Comment: It looks like the security tab is trying to treat 'ClientMember' as a DataObject $item->setSourceQueryParams($this->dataQuery()->getQueryParams()); (form DataList.php createDataObject())

Comment: That's strange. I have used the same method in projects before and never had this issue. I'll try the exact code in my answer and see if I can recreate your issue.

Comment: I thought that too, I trashed the ClientMember table. Might need to do the same to Member?

Comment: So strange. I have quadruple checked everything... Is your cms and framework up to date? I am on 3.1 with latest commit for both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82888/discussion-between-3dgoo-and-nickspiel).

Comment: Fo those interested, I had to trash the tables associated to Members and rebuild, after that it all worked as expected.